# Passport.js - Is it possible to pass a parameter into the router authenticated function?

Tags: node.js, express, authorization, passport.js

I would like to pass a certain permission into the authenticated call on routes in Passport.js.

This is what I have now:

```
app.get('/mypage', app.authenticated, function (req, res, next) {
    if (!req.user.hasPermission('myPermission')) {
        return res.redirect('/unauthorized');
    }

    // do stuff
};

﻿var middleware = function(app) {
    app.authenticated = function (req, res, next) {
        if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
            return next();
        }

        if (req.method == 'GET') {
            req.session.returnTo = req.originalUrl;
        }

        res.redirect('/login');
    };
}

module.exports = middleware;
```

I would instead like to pass the permission into `authenticated` like this:

```
app.get('/mypage', app.authenticated('myPermission'), function (req, res, next) {
    // do stuff
};
```

But as far as I can tell, since authenticated gets the parameters it needs automatically, I can't just add a new one.

How can I go about doing this?

Comment: take a look at https://github.com/OptimalBits/node_acl/

Answer (score 0):

You can access **req.body** values in any of the express middleware.

In your `app.authenticated(..)` middleware, prior to execution set the value :
`req.body['permission'] = 'myPermission'`

Use the value of req.body['permission'] for authorisation.